# How to extract a set of *.tar.gz.(letters) files?

Tags: dataset, extract

I have downloaded a medical data set to use in machine learning and the files are like this:

```
dicom_v1.tar.gz.aa
dicom_v1.tar.gz.ab
dicom_v1.tar.gz.ac
dicom_v1.tar.gz.ad
```

I don't know how to extract these files. When I use *WinRAR* or *7-Zip*, it doesn't work.

It is written in the attached `ReadMe` file:

> To decompress this data set execute in a Unix command line:
> `cat dicom_archive.tar.* | tar -xzvf`

How can I do this in Windows 10 as I am a beginner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These files have been `split` into chunks for distribution, so you need to put them back together before you can see whether Winrar or 7-zip will be able to extract them.

Since you're using Windows, you probably want to the Powershell `get-content` command (which helpfully aliased to `cat` btw) - and since the files are chunks of a compressed archive you probably want to use the `-raw` argument too.

https://shellgeek.com/use-cat-equivalent-type-command-in-windows/ is a good page to read.

I would try something like this as a starting point:

```
PS C:\> get-content -raw dicom_v1.tar.gz.* > dicom_v1.tar.gz
```

According to https://pureinfotech.com/extract-tar-gz-files-windows-10/ you should be able to run `tar` with the `z` flag natively in Powershell to extract all the files from the dicom archive.

Comment: Thank you For Your Response ,when i run the Command it gave me this text in red:get-content : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-content -raw dicom_archive_v2.tar.gz.* > dicom_archive_v2.tar.gz
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-Content], OutOfMemoryException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderContentReadError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Each File is a 3GB , and There are about 15 Files , so the Whole Thing is about 45 GB

Comment: The Above Message is displayed for 15 Times (The Number of Files) in the Power Shell Window

Comment: Ouch. Does the distributor of the data provide a complete archive file you could download instead?

Comment: Sadly , No , Is there still a Solution ? .As this is very important to me !

Comment: You're going to need a virtual machine of some sort - either WSL2 on your system, or a linux container in Docker or an EC2. Then use the cat pipeline the data authors suggested before moving the output back to your system.

Comment: Actually , Most of the things you are describing  , i don't understand  . Do you think if i enable the Linux Subsystem on the Windows and run the Command , Will it Work ?

Comment: WSL2 should work. The other options I suggested are different ways of approaching the idea of getting access to a linux environment.

Comment: The Solution Was Actually Available in windows using this Command: type *.tar.gz.* | tar xvfz -

Comment: There was no Need For Linux  . Thank you very much